# Struct inside template class is not recognized by Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to re-implement a singly-linked list class with `template`s. Below is the code that has troubles.

```
template<typename T>
class list
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        node* next;
        T data;

        node( T d ) : next( nullptr ), data( d ) {}
    };
    node* first_node;
    size_t m_size;
public:
    list() : first_node( nullptr ), size( 0 ) {}
    // ...
};
```

Everything is ok, until I try to use (i.e in a method `push_back()`) members of a `node*` type variable. Example:

```
void push_back( const T& data ) 
{
    node* temp = first_node;
    while( temp->next )
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    // ...
}
```

While I am typing `temp->`, Visual Studio's IntelliSense should bring up a context menu to show the members of the `node` structure. It is not doing this. Also, when I hover the `next` word in my code, the tooltip looks like this:

[image: <unknown> list<T>::node::next]

**Let me say it clear:** I don't get any debugging error, but my question is: Why isn't Visual Studio 2013 able to compute those things?

Comment: In short, there is no problem at all with your program, only with the GUI of VS? Or did i misunderstand?

Comment: my program runs correctly, so there is no problem with the code. the problem is with the VS IntelliSense and GUI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not unexpected and is not an error.  You are writing a template, the IntelliSense parser doesn't know what *concrete* type the *next* member belongs to.  That cannot be known until *later* in your code you instantiate, say, a `list<int>`.  So it gives you what it knows, it certainly does know that `temp->next` is a `list<T>::node` and tells you so, just not for which particular kind of `list`.  So it prefixes `<unknown>`.

You could certainly argue that it should display `template class<T> list<T>::node::next` instead.  Not so sure that spins everybody's propeller, or if this is at all capability of the EDG parser (doubtful), you can make your case at [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) and file a bug report.

Comment: so what you are saying is that there is no solution for my problem, right?

Comment: I am saying that you don't actually have a problem.  So of course you don't need to look for a solution when you don't have a problem.  Pretty important that you got that from the answer btw.  Again, *it is not an error*,  errors make a lot more noise.  They fill the Error List window and use red pixels in the editor window.  The `<unknown>` annotation just means "I dont know what you are going to do with this yet".  It doesn't, it is a template.  A cookie-cutter, it needs to be *used* to do something meaningful, make cookies.

Comment: @HansPassant: The reason it can't show `list<T>::node::next` is because it can't know if the template class is specialized, specializations may have different members, or be undefined.